# Number formatting from cents to dollars

Tags: python, python-2.7, number-formatting

I'm trying to use Python 2.7's string formatting to output in dollars the cost of ten apples, where the unit price is provided in cents.

I would like the value of `total_apple_cost` to be `"10.00"`, but it's `"1.001.001.001.001.001.001.001.001.001.00"`.

I have included tests for the other variables to show that they are all coming out as expected:

```
# define apple cost in cents
apple_cost_in_cents = 100
# define format string
cents_to_dollars_format_string = '{:,.2f}'
# convert 100 to 1.00
apple_cost_in_dollars = cents_to_dollars_format_string.format(apple_cost_in_cents / 100.)
# assign value of 'apple_cost_in_dollars' to 'apple_cost'
apple_cost = apple_cost_in_dollars
# calculate the total apple cost
total_apple_cost = 10 * apple_cost

# print out the total cost
print 'total apple cost: ' + str(total_apple_cost) + '\n'

#testing
print 'cost in cents: ' + str(apple_cost_in_cents) + '\n'
print 'cost in dollars: ' + str(apple_cost_in_dollars) + '\n'
print 'apple cost: ' + str(apple_cost) + '\n'
```

**solution:**

thank you to answers below which both indicated that the variable 'apple_cost_in_dollars' was a string.

my solution was to make it a float and keep the rest of the code pretty much the same:

```
apple_cost_in_cents = 100
cents_to_dollars_format_string = '{:,.2f}'
apple_cost_in_dollars = float(cents_to_dollars_format_string.format(apple_cost_in_cents / 100.))
apple_cost = apple_cost_in_dollars
total_apple_cost = 10 * apple_cost

print 'cost in cents: ' + str(apple_cost_in_cents) + '\n'

print 'cost in dollars: $''{:,.2f}'.format(apple_cost_in_dollars) + '\n'

print 'apple cost: $''{:,.2f}'.format(apple_cost) + '\n'

print 'total apple cost: $''{:,.2f}'.format(total_apple_cost) + '\n'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is because `apple_cost_in_dollars` is a string, see below

```
In [9]: cost = '1'

In [10]: cost * 10
Out[10]: '1111111111'

In [11]: cost = int('1')

In [12]: cost * 10
Out[12]: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

`apple_cost` is a string, which you're multiplying by 10 (which simply repeats the string 10 times). Do the conversion to dollars before you format it as a string.

```
>>> apple_cost_in_cents = 100
>>> cents_to_dollars_format_string = '{:,.2f}'
>>> total_apple_cost_in_dollars_as_string = cents_to_dollars_format_string.format(10*apple_cost_in_cents/100.0)
>>> total_apple_cost_in_dollars_as_string
'10.00'
```

If you want to go further with formatting currencies you can look at the the [locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) module and specifically the `locale.currency` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import locale
>>> apple_cost_in_cents = 100
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> locale.currency(apple_cost_in_cents * 10 / 100)
'$10.00'
```

Answer (score 1):

It was formatted to a string (text). So if u write 10 * string_variable, it just repeated that string 10 times. The easiest way is change this line:

`total_apple_cost = 10 * apple_cost`

to:

`total_apple_cost = cents_to_dollars_format_string.format(10 * apple_cost_in_cents/100)`